# Confusion about the order of CSS transform

Tags: css, matrix, transform

All:

When I try CSS transform, something about the order of scale and translate confused me:

```
<svg>
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="20" height="30" style="stroke: #3333cc; fill:none;"/>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="20" height="30" style="stroke: #000000; fill:none;" transform="scale(2) translate(10, 10)"/>
</svg>


<svg>
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="20" height="30" style="stroke: #3333cc; fill:none;"/>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="20" height="30" style="stroke: #000000; fill:none;" transform="translate(10, 10) scale(2)"/>
</svg>
```

These two give different effects. Could anyone give me some explanation about how the CSS transform be processed and rendered?

Thanks

Comment: _These two give different effects._ I see the same thing twice in jsfiddle: a black rectangle overlapping a small purple rectangle located at the left top corner. Can you give some more detail about what you're seeing versus what you expected to see?

Comment: @BSMP Sorry my bad. I edit my question. The transform attr in second svg should be "translate(10, 10) scale(2)" rather than "scale(2) translate(10, 10)"

Answer (score 1):

From [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#RectElement)

> x = ""
>       The x-axis coordinate of the side of the rectangle which has the smaller x-axis coordinate value in the current user coordinate system.

and [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/x):

> This attribute indicates an x-axis coordinate in the user coordinate
>   system. The exact effect of this coordinate **depend on each element**.

The reason they don't look the same is because scaling the element also scaled the user coordinate system.

I've added two more SVG elements so we can see what it looks like with just the first transform applied to it.

```html
<svg>
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="20" height="30" style="stroke: #3333cc; fill:none;"/>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="20" height="30" style="stroke: #000000; fill:none;" transform="scale(2)"/>
</svg>

<svg>
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="20" height="30" style="stroke: #3333cc; fill:none;"/>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="20" height="30" style="stroke: #000000; fill:none;" transform="scale(2) translate(10, 10)"/>
</svg>


<svg>
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="20" height="30" style="stroke: #3333cc; fill:none;"/>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="20" height="30" style="stroke: #000000; fill:none;" transform="translate(10, 10)"/>
</svg>


<svg>
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="20" height="30" style="stroke: #3333cc; fill:none;"/>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="20" height="30" style="stroke: #000000; fill:none;" transform="translate(10, 10) scale(2)"/>
</svg>
```

In the first one the scale is applied first. Now both the rect and the user coordinate system is 2x as big as the purple rect. So when it is moved to 10,10 that is not the same location as it is for the purple rect.

In the second, the rect is moved first. It has the same coordinate system as the purple rect so it ends up in the exact same place. It is *then* scaled so it's upper left hand corner stays in the same place.

Answer (score 1):

Every transform function like scale, translate represents a matrix. And matrix concatenation/multiplication is not commutative. So M1 x M2 must not be equal to M2 x M1.

E.g. a scaling matrix (column major order), scale(2, 2):

```
m11=2.000   m21=0.000   m31=0.000
m12=0.000   m22=2.000   m32=0.000
m13=0.000   m23=0.000   m33=1.000
```

E.g. a translation matrix, translate(10, 10):

```
m11=1.000   m21=0.000   m31=10.000
m12=0.000   m22=1.000   m32=10.000
m13=0.000   m23=0.000   m33=1.000
```

Scale * Translate:

```
m11=2.000   m21=0.000   m31=20.000
m12=0.000   m22=2.000   m32=20.000
m13=0.000   m23=0.000   m33=1.000
```

Translate * Scale:

```
m11=2.000   m21=0.000   m31=10.000
m12=0.000   m22=2.000   m32=10.000
m13=0.000   m23=0.000   m33=1.000
```

Comment: `scale(t)` is a matrix transform `(t 0; 0 t)` for sure, but translation is the addition of a vector, which can't (generally, the zero vector being a trivial case where it's equivalent to transforming by the identity matrix) be represented as a matrix transform.

Comment: @Robin, do you talk about a 2x2 matrix? That would be just the linear part of the matrix. The matrix mentioned above is a 3x3 matrix (inlcuding the perspective stuff -> last row, and the translation -> last column).

Comment: I think I follow you. In this formulation, are we representing the position `(x,y)` by column vector `(x ; y ; 1)`? This is a great explanation with the matrices included, kudos.